# Applying lambda function in two data frames in the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames and I want to apply only one lambda function in both of them in the same time. They are string.

```
df1:

    A   B   C
0   1   1   2
1   2   0   0
2   1   2   2
3   1.5 1   3

df2:

    A   B
0   3   1   
1   4   5   
2   2.7 2   
3   3.1 4
```

Some Thing like :

```
df1["A"] = df1["A"].apply(lambda x: float(x))
df2["A"] = df2["A"].apply(lambda x: float(x))
```

In only one line. I heard I could use something like:

```
map(lambda x: x.query(float(x)), [df1, df2])
```

But it is returning me a map object and I do not know what to do with that.
Thanks.

Comment: You can convert the map object by using `list(map(lambda x: x.query(float(x)), [df1, df2])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need convert output to list of Dataframes with `astype` function:

```
dfs = list(map(lambda x: x.astype(float), [df1, df2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your dataframes in a list and use a list comprehension:

```
my_df_list = [df1, df2]

[df.apply(lambda x: float(x)) for df in my_df_list]
```